# Customizable Authorize attribute in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am using Jwt Token authentication in Asp.Net Core, in order to authenticate I am using built in attribute `[Authorize]`, what I want to do is that make this attribute customizable, means I want to make this attribute configurable, to either enable it or disable authentication and I can place the setting in `appsetting.json`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use Policy-based authorization to achieve your requirement.

I suggest you could write a custom Handler to compare the appsetting.json value and the route value.

If the appsetting.json value contains the request the route value, then you could return Succeed to avoid auth.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Appseting.json(DisableAuthController value)

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "DisableAuthController": "home,default,account"
  }
}
```

Create a new class named: UserResourceHandler

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FormAuthCore
{
    public class UserResourceHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserResourceRequirement>
    {

        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public UserResourceHandler(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));


        }

        protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authHandlerContext, UserResourceRequirement requirement)
        {

            var re = Configuration.GetSection("DisableAuthController").Value;

            var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
                var area = (context.Values["area"] as string)?.ToLower();
                var controller = (context.Values["controller"] as string)?.ToLower();
                var action = (context.Values["action"] as string)?.ToLower();

                if (re.Contains(controller))
                {
                    authHandlerContext.Succeed(requirement);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Create a UserResourceRequirement class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace FormAuthCore
{
    public class UserResourceRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }   
}
```

Add below codes into Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
      services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("UserResource", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserResourceRequirement()));
        });

        services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserResourceHandler>();
```

Enable Policy-based authorization for the controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UserResource")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

---

Update:

I added token1 jwt token auth in the startup.cs

```
            services.AddAuthentication("Token1")
                .AddJwtBearer("Token1", options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
           ValidateIssuer = true,
           ValidIssuer = "abc",
           ValidateAudience = true,
           ValidAudience = "abc",
           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")),
       };
       options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
       {
           OnMessageReceived = context =>
           {
               var Token = context.Request.Headers["UserCred1"].ToString();
               context.Token = Token;
               return Task.CompletedTask;
           },
       };
   });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("UserResource", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserResourceRequirement()));
            });

            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserResourceHandler>();
```

Then I could use `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Token1").Result` to check if the token is valid or not.

```
  protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authHandlerContext, UserResourceRequirement requirement)
    {


        var re = Configuration.GetSection("DisableAuthController").Value;

        var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
        var re2 = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Token1").Result;

            var area = (context.Values["area"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var controller = (context.Values["controller"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var action = (context.Values["action"] as string)?.ToLower();

            if (re.Contains(controller) || re2.Succeeded)
            {
                authHandlerContext.Succeed(requirement);
            }



    }
```

Comment: ok I got your point, I thing more that this handler should check if jwt token that was generated is valid or not How can i achieve that? @Brando Zhand

Comment: You could use ` _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("authenticationSchemename").Result;`  to check if the  jwt token is  valid or not. Detials, you could see my update answer.

Comment: and this will also check if token is expired not ?

Comment: and one thing more I am getting this error No SecurityTokenValidator available for token: Bearer : @Brando Zhang